# ORA-01465: invalid hex number, when inserting data to oracle table

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm working under Oracle, and when want to insert a simple insert query I got the below error

> ORA-01465: invalid hex number

Knowing that I don't have any specific column in my table.

I have tried lot of solutions on the web but without any success.

```
INSERT INTO LIMITE_AGENC (OBJECTID_1, OBJECTID, NOM_AGENCE, SURFACE, BASSIN, 
    NOM, SHAPE_LENG, ID_REG, ORDRE_ABH)
VALUES 
   (30, 25, 'Agence', 13591, 'Hydraulique', 
    'Loukkomoti', 8.12883522, 12, 3);
```

and here is my table script, I have updated the script with more details if you need to check the index part...

```
DROP TABLE LIMITE_AGENC CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;

CREATE TABLE LIMITE_AGENC
(
  OBJECTID_1  INTEGER,
  OBJECTID    INTEGER,
  NOM_AGENCE  NVARCHAR2(80),
  SURFACE     INTEGER,
  BASSIN      NVARCHAR2(100),
  NOM         NVARCHAR2(50),
  SHAPE_LENG  NUMBER(38,8),
  SHAPE       SDE.ST_GEOMETRY,
  ID_REG      INTEGER,
  ORDRE_ABH   INTEGER
)
LOB ("SHAPE"."POINTS") STORE AS BASICFILE (
  TABLESPACE  USERS
  ENABLE      STORAGE IN ROW
  CHUNK       8192
  PCTVERSION  10
  NOCACHE
  LOGGING
      STORAGE    (
                  INITIAL          64K
                  NEXT             1M
                  MINEXTENTS       1
                  MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
                  PCTINCREASE      0
                  BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
                 ))
TABLESPACE USERS
PCTUSED    0
PCTFREE    10
INITRANS   1
MAXTRANS   255
STORAGE    (
            INITIAL          64K
            NEXT             1M
            MAXSIZE          UNLIMITED
            MINEXTENTS       1
            MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
            PCTINCREASE      0
            BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
           )
LOGGING 
NOCOMPRESS 
NOCACHE
MONITORING;


CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_CONST_AGENCE2 ON LIMITE_AGENC
(OBJECTID)
LOGGING
TABLESPACE USERS
PCTFREE    10
INITRANS   2
MAXTRANS   255
STORAGE    (
            INITIAL          64K
            NEXT             1M
            MAXSIZE          UNLIMITED
            MINEXTENTS       1
            MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
            PCTINCREASE      0
            BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
           );

ALTER TABLE LIMITE_AGENC ADD (
  CONSTRAINT UNIQ_CONST_AGENCE2
  UNIQUE (OBJECTID)
  USING INDEX UNIQ_CONST_AGENCE2
  ENABLE VALIDATE);

GRANT SELECT ON LIMITE_AGENC TO SDE;
```

Comment: Cannot replicate your error [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9f5061f0be0c620fb00f5cc5bc967363).

Comment: Hi, I have added the script of my table

Comment: Still cannot replicate your error [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7dc41dbdc9a7f87fc4f9713ff9d0c052). (Left out the storage options, as I can't get them to work on db<>fiddle, but I can't see how they would affect the error).

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have found the issue, so the problem is that I have to add the geometry column **Shape** in my request with an empty value as below

```
Insert into LIMITE_AGENC (OBJECTID_1, OBJECTID, NOM_AGENCE, SURFACE, BASSIN, 
    NOM, SHAPE_LENG,SHAPE, ID_REG, ORDRE_ABH)
 Values
   (30, 25, 'Agence', 13591, 'Hydraulique', 
    'Loukkomoti', 8.12883522, '', 12, 3);
```

I hope that would help someone in the future